# Passing named arguments and variable number of arguments in block call

Tags: ruby, syntax, yield

I have a piece of test code:

```
def asdf(id: nil, field: nil, state: nil)
  puts "id: #{id}, field: #{field}"
end

def test(a, b, *args)
  # a, b are needed only inside #test
  yield(state: :created, *args)
end

test('a', 'b', id: 'xyz', field: :asd) { |*args| asdf(*args) }
```

It generates a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected *
yield(state: :created, *args)
```

What is the correct way to call a block with a named parameter and an argument list? What is the idiomatic way to do this?

I also tried passing `&block` to `test` and doing `block.call(state: :created, *args)` with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up splat and double splat (note, that I changed all `*args` to `**args`):

```
def asdf(id: nil, field: nil, state: nil)
  puts "id: #{id}, field: #{field}"
end

def test(a, b, **args)
  # a, b are needed only inside #test
  yield(state: :created, **args)
end

test('a', 'b', id: 'xyz', field: :asd) { |**args| asdf(**args) }
#⇒ id: xyz, field: asd
```

Splat is used for unknown amount of *plain* params:

```
def test a, b, *args
  puts args.inspect
end
test 42, true, 'additional'
#⇒ ["additional"]
```

Double splat, introduced in Ruby2, is used to receive hash (named params):

```
def test a, b, **args
  puts args.inspect
end
test 42, true, hello: 'world'
#⇒ {:hello=>"world"}
```

Comment: You are correct about the OP's mistake. But to be precise, that is not the **direct** cause of the syntax error (it would only cause an argument error). The reason for the syntax error is because named parameter (`state: :created`) was placed before `*`. However, what you pointed out is the **indirect** cause of the error.